# Smallest Common Multiple Code produces the wrong answer on one array

Tags: javascript

[edit]

I should clarify, I am attempting to find the smallest common multiple of a range of numbers. Sorry about that. I have attempted another solution but I still run into an incorrect answer on the last array [23, 18].

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });

  var count = 1;

  for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
    if (count % i !== 0) {
      i = arr[0];
      count++;
    } 
  }

  return count;
}


smallestCommons([23,18]);
```

My solution produces 2018940 when it should be 6056820

Comment: What is that that loop between the values of your array supposed to achieve?

Comment: It loops between the numbers between the two arguments.

Comment: I see your comment to one of the answers that yo actually need to find smallest common multiple of a range. You need to include these details in your original question. Your code is probably correct, but it probably takes too long to run. They may have expected you to use a smarter way to calculate it. If they asked for [11, 20] then that's potentially over 10^10 times you would need to loop.

Comment: I changed my code and question to reflect this

Answer (score 3):

Your endless loop is becouse of your inner for loop which starts at the value 19 and runs to 22

```
414 (smallestMultiple of 18 & 23) % 19 == 15
414 % 20 = 14
414 % 21 = 15
414 % 22 = 18
```

which leads to your statement if(count % i == 0) being false and your for loop goes on with 415 416 ...

if u want to get the 
least common multiple

```
var isSmallestMultipe = 0;
while(isSmallestMultiple == 0)
{
   for(var i = 1; i <= arr[1]; i+)
   {
      if((arr[0]*i) % arr[1] == 0)
      {
         isSmallestMultiple = arr[0] * i;           
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: interesting. Okay, so just to clarify: I'm multiplying the first argument by I and modding that by the second argument. If that equals 0, then it's the smallest multiple of those two numbers. The issue for me is that this problem also requires that I find the smallest multiple of the numbers between the two arguments as well. That's what my inner loop was trying to accomplish (the loop that goes on forever).